Movie about a high school teacher
One night while I was half asleep I wondered upon a movie on some random Channel: 

It was about a male teacher who recently got a job at a high school in LA which was really “trashy”, and a lot of the students didn’t respect him and they weren't learning.
Eventually they began to ease up on him and they started to enjoy his class.  
I also remember the principal was female, and she got arrested at the end of the movie. 
It was in color! It looked like it could’ve been from the late 80s or 90s. 
There was a few scenes in China Town, one where the teacher got drunk/high. 
There was also some gang, but that’s about all I can remember.

There was also a scene of a car running off a cliff, if that is any help. 

Welcome to Movies SE! Is there anything else you could add? anymore of the plot? where was the movie filmed? Was it in Black and white or in colour? What did the background look like? Awesome that you have already stated that it was based in New York City, When do you believe the film was showing or when did you see it? Some questions in this comment might seem way off, but remember to include as much detail as possible when asking identify-this-movie questions. Good Try Though!

This doesn't entirely fit your description, since it is set in Los Angeles, not in New York, but else has many things in common:
High School High
Comedy from 1996 about a new teacher (Jon Lovitz) at a trashy school. They give him a hard time at the beginning, but later enjoy the class. There is a gang, and a female principal (played by One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest's Louise Fletcher), who is arrested at the end of the movie.
The movie features a parody of Rebel Without A Cause's car race towards a cliff-scene (I'm not sure, if one of the cars runs of the cliff, though). 
Trailer:  



Neither of these match your description perfectly, but I feel like they are the most likely candidates. 
Stand and Deliver (1988)

Jaime Escalante is a mathematics teacher in a school in a Hispanic neighbourhood. Convinced that his students have potential, he adopts unconventional teaching methods help gang members and no-hopers pass the rigorous Advanced Placement exam in calculus. 

  Source: IMDB


Lean on Me (1989)

An arrogant and unorthodox teacher returns as principal to the idyllic high school from which he had earlier been fired to find it a den of drug abuse, gang violence, and urban despair. Eventually his successful but unorthodox methods lead to a clash with city officials that threatens to undo all his efforts. Based on a true story. 

  Source: IMDB



Greetings!  Please provide 2 separate answers for each movie.  Thank you :)
